# Nativescript Textfield text and hint attribute not showing in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, textfield

I can not see text i typed (cursor moves as I type) and even the hint attribute of textfield is not displaying as well in IOS 13.1.3 using javascript nativescript. Has anyone run into this issue? My app has no issue when run in Adroid. I'm using the following. Sidekick Version: 1.19.1-v.2019.8.1.2 (latest)
NativeScript CLI version: 6.1.2
CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.18.2
CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try assigning color on TextField? Are you testing with light / dark mode?

Comment: hehehe... thanks to dual platform testing i can keep moving on...damn updates.. Thanks you very much sir.